# Vue | How to store private information between pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, backend

I have a form with 6 questions on 'form' page. I add input values to `userData` object after switching questions. At the end of the form I send userData to firebase.

But when I switch pages, the `userData` object clears.

How to store `userData` between pages? I don't want to use `localStorage` because it is unsafe.

Comment: Why do you feel localStorage is unsafe?

Comment: The postulate regarding localstorage is usually repeated thoughtlessly. If culprits can access client's LS, they most likely can access everything. Client side is unsafe by its meaning.

Comment: If you feel like localStorage is unsafe for your usecase (which I'm not sure it is), you could use something like vue-router, because that prevents the browser from actually reloading the page, so your state stays the same. Also sessionStorage might be a safer alternative for your usecase.

Comment: @Moritur, yeah, I use vue-router and the page doesn't reload after switching, but the userData object clears anyway

Comment: @EstusFlask. That's what I wanted to answer to ceejayoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

> Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion.

Comment: Vuex doesn't actually persist state between navigation. There are plugins which do persist the vuex state in localstorage, but the explicitly stated that they didn't want to do that.

Comment: @Moritur, actually it helped me